# Azure Functions OpenID Connect (Preview) Setup Internal Server Error

Tags: azure-functions, openid, auth0

I followed the instructions here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-openid-connect
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#config-file

And found this blog post incredibly helpful:

- https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-app-service-openid-connect-auth0/

To setup open id connect so that my azure functions could integrate with my auth0 configuration including the setup to use the config file support for azure functions authentication modules.

My auth.json file looks like this:

```json
{
    "platform": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "globalValidation": {
        "requireAuthentication": true,
        "redirectToProvider": "auth0",
        "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage"
    },
    "identityProviders": {
        "openIdConnectProviders": {
            "auth0": {
                "enabled": true,
                "registration": {
                    "clientId": "******************",
                    "clientCredential": {
                        "secretSettingName": "AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET"
                    },
                    "openIdConnectConfiguration": {
                        "wellKnownOpenIdConfiguration": "https://*********.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
                    }
                },
                "login": {
                    "nameClaimType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
                    "scope": ["openid", "profile", "email"],
                    "loginParameters": []
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "login": {
        "tokenStore": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

It deploys properly and all the files are properly updated and in place with the proper config-file props. However, upon triggering a function (httptrigger) I receive a 500 Internal Server Error. After some digging through the logs, I stumbled on to the following:

```
2020-09-02T18:23:53  PID[5492] Critical    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware.OpenIdConnectProvider.GetLoginRedirectUrlAsync(HttpContextBase context, String callbackUrl, String postLoginRedirectUrl, NameValueCollection oauthState, String nonce)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware.IdentityProviderBase.<RedirectToLoginPageAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware.EasyAuthModule.<AuthenticateAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware.EasyAuthModule.<OnAuthenticateRequestAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware.HttpModuleDispatcher.<DispatchAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
2020-09-02T18:23:53  PID[5492] Information Sending response: 500.79 Internal Server Error
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated! I know it's just in preview, but it's still something I'd like to use if possible.

Comment: I prefer to to the configuration in code instead of JSON, because then you more easilly spot typos and errors.

Comment: @ToreNestenius that is not applicable to the question at hand. This is the only way to set it up with azure functions as far as I can tell. If you know anything different please feel free to contribute in a helpful manner.